# Are similar circles really a thing?

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm a fifteen year old who is currently studying circle geometry (if that is the appropriate term) and our teacher stated that concentric circles are similar. I thought about this, and it doesn't make sense to me. The reason is because of proportionality. For example, similar triangles are similar because they have the same angles and they have proportional sides. However, circles can not be compared for angles, so that's out (as they all have the same 360 degree angle at the center) and the only factor is their size, which is directly influenced by their radius. If the radius is the only variable involved in a triangle like this, how can a circle be NOT proportional to another circle? If a case of that existed, there would be meaning (at least from my current perspective) to the term "similar circle."

Help and critique on my logic is requested, and an explanation as to the term "similar circle."

Comment: Concentric circles are similar. So are non-concentric circles.

Comment: But what is the point of the term "similar circle" if there are no cases of "non similar circles"? I'm really confused about this topic.

Comment: In a proof, one might be using the fact that (any) two circles are similar, so it may be useful to mention it.

Comment: You are right, in Euclidean geometry all circles are similar. Likewise, all parabolas are similar.

Comment: "similar" does not only refer to circles. It refers to geometric shapes. For example, it doesn't make so much sense to speak of a rectangular square although a square is always rectangular.

Comment: Circles do not have a 360 degree angle in the middle. A polygon's angle is between *segments* of its perimeter. I don't believe it would be correct to talk about line segments on a circle; off-hand, I suspect you could show that between any two points on the circle's perimeter, you could show that the segment is in the circle's interior and not on the border. So since you can't really have line segments on the edges, I'm not sure how you'd talk about a circle's angles. Maybe you could do something with limits; this would take you into calculus territory, though.

Comment: Concensus.  All circles (and squares, and parabolas, and others) are similar.  So "similar circle" imo is an unnecessary redundancy.  Anyway, I must say, that was a well-reasoned and insightful observation on your part.  And you expressed and argued it very well.  I'm quite impressed.

Comment: @jpmc26 the op is *clearly* talking about the interior angle.  He/she even  specifical stated circles don't have angles as polygons do.  So you are really only repeating the op stated.  Give the op some credit.  It was an insightful and accurate observation.

Comment: @fleablood I wasn't trying to suggest the post isn't insightful or useful. My apologies if it sounded that way. It was merely a comment on a minor detail that didn't seem to make a lot of sense. There aren't any boundaries at the center of the circle to talk about an angle between, and when talking about closed geometries, "angles" refer to angles between segments on the boundary in all contexts I know of. All I was trying to say was that particular phrase seems wonky and there's probably a better way to talk about the point that was intended or potentially clear up a little confusion.

Comment: I always found the term _similar_ to be a misnomer, sounding way too weak. Two objects are similar only if they're basically _the same object_ (just seen in different scale). And well, circles are basically all the same, just scaled and placed at different spots.

Comment: @bof: That's a very interesting comment! To expand on it, note that parabolas are special, lying in-between ellipses and hyperbolas, and all parabolas are similar (translated scaled rotations of one another) though there are non-similar ellipses and non-similar hyperbolas. It's related to the 'strange' fact that the parabola has one focus at $\infty$ and so we can use translation, scaling and rotation to bring the focus and the base (intersection of curve and its major axis) anywhere we like. This isn't true for ellipses and hyperbolas because their focii are both not at $\infty$.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're right: any two circles are similar (and so there's not much point of talking about "similar circles")!  In general, two shapes are "congruent" if you can turn one into the other by translations (moving around in the plane), rotations, and reflections.  Two shapes are "similar" if you can rescale ("zoom in or out" on the picture) one of them to turn it into a shape that is congruent to the other.  Given two circles, you can rescale one so that it has the same radius as the other, and then any two circles with the same radius are congruent since you can just translate the center of one to the center of the other.

Comment: Nice explanation, appreciated by the OP. Just to whet his eighth grade appetite: if you think about geometry on the surface of a sphere you'll see that a pair of similar triangles must in fact be congruent. There's no "zooming in or out".

Comment: @EthanBolker Don't confuse him - nonEuclidean geometry is neither useful to him nor relevant to him now...

Comment: @Daniel The OP has asked some other interesting questions and is mathematically adventurous for his age. I'm not sure when (spherical) nonEuclidean geometry is either particularly useful or relevant (other than for navigation?) but it can be eye opening. If he finds my suggestion intriguing he can follow it and probably won't be confused by it. Or he can ignore it.

Comment: Oh I have nothing against mathematical exploration.  I'm 17 and I love learning new things, but I know that when I was 15 and taking geometry, spherical geometry just about drove me insane.  I don't think I was ready for it at the time.  He very well may be ready, but you should at least provide a disclaimer...

Comment: I just happened to see a really good video on this yesterday by Matt Parker, "There is only One True Parabola": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoh4TmPzu1w

Comment: @EthanBolker, the aspect of your statement that will confuse the uninitiated is: That's not geometry on the surface of *a* sphere, it's geometry on the surface of an *abstract* sphere which can be (itself) of any size that is convenient.  In other words you are redefining "congruent" to mean "casts the same outward shadow from the infinitely powerful light source at the center of our abstract sphere."  Hardly intuitive to an eighth grader (though not difficult to understand when fully explained).

Answer (score 12):

Yes indeed. Every circle is similar. You can always scale one of them to match the other. Actually, this is the definition of similarity. In case of triangles, this definition yields the result that the sides are proportional. "The sides of one triangle are proportional to the other" is not the actual definition of similarity.
You may have a look [here](https://learnzillion.com/resources/73031-prove-that-all-circles-are-similar)